# Update a single property in a REST API

Tags: rest

In designing a new API, we are doing our best to follow the patterns established by REST. The question I have is the best method to follow when trying to update a single property. For example:

Imagine you have a simple Car resource:

```
{
   "make": "Chevrolet",
   "model": "Chevelle",
   "year": 1966,
   "color": "black",
   "for_sale": true
}
```

Let's assume that the property `for_sale` is something that you anticipate will be updated regularly by the user. I have a couple options:

1. `PUT` the entire resource with `for_sale` set to `false`. For a reasonably small resource, this seems fine, however, in most cases our resources are quite large so a lot of waste in sending the entire resource to update a single, often changed property.
2. `POST` and do a partial update by only including the element to update, such as:
   `{"for_sale":false}` This is better as it requires a lot less overhead.

But I somehow seem to be reaching for something even more simple, but I don't seem to find the right approach. It would be quite convenient to offer a simple `PUT` to a URL (that doesn't require any request body) to update this property. I see what Google is doing in their API to accomplish this, but it feels just a bit RPC-ish, although I like the simplicity.

`POST`  `/blogs/blogId/posts/postId/comments/commentId/approve`
(marks a comment as not spam)

`POST`  `/blogs/blogId/posts/postId/comments/commentId/spam` (marks a comment as spam)

Can someone offer some advice on the best way to approach updating a single property within a resource (in a preferably lightweight manner) that followed REST principles?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Actually, I think that the PATCH method is designed specifically for this purpose. You should use it to provide a partial update to the object, rather than a full update. [Here is a blog entry](http://www.mnot.net/blog/2012/09/05/patch) that explains this in more detail.

Comment: I covered the PUT vs PATCH debate, as well as the "partial update" topic in this blog post: http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/. Basically, it is not a RESTful feature, however it is still ok to do partially update, and the PATCH method is the most appropriate solution.

Comment: @WilliamDURAND as you say in your blog, you can use whatever format you want for the patch body -- although clearly rfc6902 is nice -- assuming that all patches are simple updates and passing a property = value list would suffice to solve the specific problem mentioned here, where there is no clear need for full a full diff protocol.

Comment: You must define how to "update" properties, so you need a format that defines that, hence the need for RFC6902 or similar, not just whatever format. This format must define how to perform the changes.

Comment: No, the semantics can be implied. There is no 'must'. Where the application can 'only' replace the named value with the one given there is no need for a full diff protocol, and indeed it would be wasteful to have one. The IT world has gotten along just fine for decades without such a protocol, so 'must' is a very strong word to use. Of course, I'm not saying that the OP doesn't need a fuller protocol, just that this question doesn't demand one.

Comment: PATCH with http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-appsawg-json-merge-patch-02 is fine. @WilliamDURAND is overstating things.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned which is :

`PUT` the entire resource with for_sale set to false. For a reasonably small resource, this seems fine, however, in most cases our resources are quite large so a lot of waste in sending the entire resource to update a single, often changed property.

That is true, so for this kind of scenarios i will suggest the following approach :

The URI should be something like this :

`POST /api/cars/C1234`

`Request Body:
{"for_sale":false}`

As not all web servers (and forget about clients) support `PATCH` so people have been supporting both partial updates with POST:

This is again not perfect RESTful API design, but i have seen and followed this one as best practice.

Comment: `POST` IMO is not meant for an update at all. It's good for creating stuff and sending some RPC, DDD style commands like `/api/cars/1/sell`. Your solution looks more like a hack.